# Plot median,lower quartile in dimplejs horizontal bar char

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have plot the simple horizontal grouped bar chart what i want is to create a point on median and lower quartile on each bar using dimpleJs tried many way still can't find how to do it?[image]

my JSON data is:

```
var data = [{
    "topic_id": 38,
    "level": "easy",
    "all_marks": [100],
    "total marks": 80,
    "name": "gamma",
    "topic label": "sec A",
    "median" : 18,
}, {
    "topic_id": 38,
    "level": "medium",
    "all_marks": [30],
    "total marks": 10,
    "name": "alpha",
    "topic label": "sec A",
    "median" : 11,
}, {
    "topic_id": 38,
    "level": "difficult",
    "all_marks": [40],
    "total marks": 10,
    "median" : 15,
    "name": "delta",
    "topic label": "sec A"
}, {
    "topic_id": 39,
    "level": "easy",
    "all_marks": [100],
    "total marks": 80,
    "median" : 13,
    "name": "gamma",
    "topic label": "sec B"
}, {
    "median" : 11,
    "topic_id": 39,
    "level": "medium",
    "all_marks": [30],
    "total marks": 10,
    "name": "alpha",
    "topic label": "sec B"
}, {
    "median" : 10,
    "topic_id": 39,
    "level": "difficult",
    "all_marks": [40],
    "total marks": 10,
    "name": "delta",
    "topic label": "sec B"
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see median in your data but not lower quartile, if you can get that in to the data in the same format as median it will be fairly straightforward to add it to the chart.  Here is an example adding median as a floating marker, you can change the series type to bubble if you would rather have dots than rectangles:

```
// Set up the chart as usual
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 800, 600);
var c = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var totalAxis = c.addMeasureAxis("x", "total marks");
var categoryAxis = c.addCategoryAxis("y", ["topic label", "level"]);
// Add an additional measure axis. By passing an axis object rather than a position letter to the first parameter
// we create a composite axis which draws both measures on the same physical axis.
var medianAxis = c.addMeasureAxis(totalAxis, "median");
// Add the bar series
var totalSeries = c.addSeries("level", dimple.plot.bar, [categoryAxis, totalAxis]);
// Add a separate bar series for median
var medianSeries = c.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar, [categoryAxis, medianAxis]);
// By setting to not be stacked on a bar series it draws floating bars which work as markers
medianSeries.stacked = false;
c.draw();
```

Here it is in action: https://jsfiddle.net/w9tjqq6c/

Comment: Hello is there Box plot available from dimpleJS?

Comment: I found some problem now on your code.. the median value is placing randomly like in bar of easy median value of difficult level is displayed ?